# iOS app communicate with an app running in OSX via usb cable connection

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa-touch

Does iOS SDK provide a way to let iOS app talk to app running in OSX/Windows via usb cable connection? 
Or, socket is the only option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Communication via USB cable is possible but everything is under **strict MFi NDA**.

One link that might interest you:

[Microchip: 3-step Approach to Develop iPod®, iPhone® and iPad® Accessories](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=2872&param=en546073)

Some more information on [Apple MFi program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/)

There are no fees to enter the program but you will have to fill out some 'paperwork'.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to interact with an OS X program from iOS via USB, the [PeerTalk](https://github.com/rsms/peertalk) lib seems to provide a convenient way to do so (without having to join the MFi program).

According to the github page, PeerTalk

> Provides you with USB device attach/detach events and attached device's info
>
> Can connect to TCP services on supported attached devices (e.g. an iPhone), bridging the communication over USB transport
>
> Offers a higher-level API (PTChannel and PTProtocol) for convenient implementations.
>
> [is] Tested and designed for libdispatch (aka Grand Central Dispatch).

It also

> has successfully been released on both the iOS and OS X app store.
>
> A great example is [Duet Display](http://www.duetdisplay.com/) which is a fantastic piece of software allowing you to use your iDevice as an extra display for your Mac using the Lightning or 30-pin cable. [...]