# Exchange data between iOS app and OS X app through USB

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I'm looking for a way to exchange data between my own iOS app and my own OS X application through a cable.

There is [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230356/exchange-data-between-ios-app-and-mac-app-through-usb-cable) for jailbroken devices, but I need solution for non-jailbroken device.

Does anyone has any suggestions?

Comment: The official iOS SDK does not support this. The only option is iTunes file sharing, but it requires the user to selected the file and move it to and from the device.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to exchange data between two apple device is iCloud, it's free and fast.

To take idCloud

```
NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
id currentiCloudToken = fileManager.ubiquityIdentityToken;
```

And to verify if it exists

```
if (currentiCloudToken) {
NSData *newTokenData =
        [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: currentiCloudToken];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
        setObject: newTokenData
           forKey: @"com.apple.MyAppName.UbiquityIdentityToken"];
} else {
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
        removeObjectForKey: @"com.apple.MyAppName.UbiquityIdentityToken"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a few people asking the same or at least very similar question (i.e. how do I exchange data between an iDevice and an OS X program via USB).

As I can't mark the question as a duplicate, I'll refer you to my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31195872/1673491) instead, or directly to [PeerTalk](https://github.com/rsms/peertalk), a library that advertises its ability to provide such functionality.